# Redux Toolkit RTK Query sending query parameters

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

How do you pass query parameters to the api using Redux Toolkit RTK Query?

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const baseUrl = 'xxxxxxx';

export const postsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'posts',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPostsByYear: builder.query({
      query: (start, end) => { // Why is 'end' always undefined???
        return {
          url: 'posts/',
          params: { start, end },
        };
      },
    }),
    getPosts: builder.query({
      query: () => 'posts/',
    }),

    getPostByID: builder.query({
      query: (name) => `posts/${name}`,
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetPostsQuery, useGetPostsByYearQuery, useGetPostByIDQuery } = postsApi;
```

When trying to pass parameters from the component only the `start` value seems to be recognised. `year` is updated by a select element within the `<PostOptions/>` component. It's using the `useState` hook. The value updates correctly and `useGetPostsByYearQuery` is called but the `end` parameter is always undefined. So, it seems I'm not defining the api endpoint correctly. Any advise? All I want it to do is send a request in the form `http://xxx/posts?start=start&end=end`.

I've even tried hard-coding a string value for the `end` parameter, e.g. `useGetPostsByYearQuery(year, '2019')`, but it still appears as `undefined` withing the api callback so I'm missing something more fundamental.

```
const Post = () => {
 
  const year = useSelector((state) => state.postOptions.year);
  const yearPlusOne = parseInt(year, 10) + 1;
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetPostsByYearQuery(year, yearPlusOne);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <PostHeading />
        <PostOptions></PostOptions>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Comment: not much to add to the answer from @slideshowp2, except this: `query` only ever takes one argument, that is why your `end` was giving you problems. The answer below shows very well how to get around that :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `QueryArg` is a generic type.

```
interface EndpointDefinitionWithQuery<
  QueryArg,
  BaseQuery extends BaseQueryFn,
  ResultType
> {
  query(arg: QueryArg): BaseQueryArg<BaseQuery>
}
```

See [source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/packages/toolkit/src/query/endpointDefinitions.ts#L56).

From the docs [Defining Query Endpoints](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#defining-query-endpoints):

> If the `query` callback needs additional data to generate the URL, it should be written to take a single argument. If you need to pass in multiple parameters, pass them formatted as a single "options object".

So you can declare the generic parameter `QueryArg` type for `builder.query` method like this:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const baseUrl = 'xxxxxxx';

export const postsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'posts',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPostsByYear: builder.query<any, { start: string; end: string }>({
      query: (arg) => {
        const { start, end } = arg;
        console.log('arg: ', arg);
        return {
          url: 'posts/',
          params: { start, end },
        };
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetPostsByYearQuery } = postsApi;
```

And pass the query arg like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useGetPostsByYearQuery } from './hooks';

export default function App() {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetPostsByYearQuery({ start: '2019', end: '2021' });
  return <div>app</div>;
}
```

The log:

```
arg:  { start: '2019', end: '2021' }
```

version: `"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0"`