# React+Redux+redux-toolki query

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a page called Goals with two cards:
[Experiment goals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSO0E.png)
And I need to set to the store an initialState as this array:

```
const initialData: Goal[] = [
  {
    label: '',
    type: 'button_click',
    target_selector: '',
    target_url: '',
    experiment_slug: '',
  },
  {
    label: '',
    type: 'link_click',
    target_selector: '',
    target_url: '',
    experiment_slug: '',
  },
]
```

And by clicking to the Add button I open the form in selected card. When I fill the form and click to the submit button I call createGoal() mutation from the RTK Query:

I have the goalsAPI.ts with mutations:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { Goal, Site } from 'interfaces'
import { Cookies } from 'react-cookie'
import { CreateGoalType, EditGoalType } from 'redux-store/types'

const cookies = new Cookies()

const BASEURL = '/api/goals'

export const goalsAPI = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'goalsAPI',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: BASEURL }),
  tagTypes: ['Goals'],
  refetchOnReconnect: true,

  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    createGoal: builder.mutation<Site, CreateGoalType>({
      query(goal) {
        return {
          url: '',
          method: 'POST',
          withCredentials: true,
          body: goal,
          headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': cookies.get('csrftoken'),
          },
        }
      },
      invalidatesTags: ['Goals'],
    }),

    editGoal: builder.mutation<Goal, EditGoalType>({
      query(body) {
        return {
          url: '',
          method: 'PATCH',
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': cookies.get('csrftoken'),
          },
          body: body,
        }
      },
      invalidatesTags: ['Goals'],
    }),

    getAllGoalsByExpSlug: builder.query<Goal[], string>({
      query(slug) {
        return {
          url: `/${slug}`,
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      },
      providesTags: ['Goals'],
    }),

    deleteGoal: builder.mutation<{ message: string }, number>({
      query(pk) {
        return {
          url: `/goal/${pk}`,
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': cookies.get('csrftoken'),
          },
        }
      },
      invalidatesTags: ['Goals'],
    })
  }),
})

export const { useCreateGoalMutation, useGetAllGoalsByExpSlugQuery, useDeleteGoalMutation, useEditGoalMutation } = goalsAPI
```

But how can I format the incoming state from the API, to set updated data to the store card?
I need do something like this:

```
if (data.length) {
  const updatedGoals = goals.map((initialGoal) => {
  const apiGoal = data.find((apiData) => apiData.type === initialGoal.type)
    return apiGoal || initialGoal
  })
  // save the updatedGoals to the store
} else {
  // save the goals to the store
}
```

I researched the problem and found the resources:
[Redux Toolkit RTK Query sending query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68158110/redux-toolkit-rtk-query-sending-query-parameters)
But it didn't help me